# Wave spawner, wave number and word length

Tags: unity

I'm trying to create a falling word typing game like z-type.

I have used the code provided here : https://github.com/Brackeys/Falling-Words-Typing-Game

In the WordSpawner.cs file, I'm trying to set the limit of the length of words that are displayed. for eg. in the first 15 seconds I want the length of words to be 3/4 and between 15-30 seconds 5/6 and after that any random length from 3 - 9. Is there any way to achieve this?

Also, I want to show the wave number on the screen like in the z-type game. How can I achieve this functionality.

This is the script from the tutorial for the word spawner:

```
public GameObject wordPrefab; 
public Transform wordCanvas; 

public WordDisplay SpawnWord () {

Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.5f, 2.5f), 7f); 
GameObject wordObj = Instantiate(wordPrefab, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity, wordCanvas); 
WordDisplay wordDisplay = wordObj.GetComponent<WordDisplay>(); 
return wordDisplay;

}
```

The list of words is an array that contains about 50 words. This list is in a separate file, WordGenerator.

```
private static string[] wordList = {   "walking", "rabbit", "bob", "save", "pablo",...... };

public static string GetRandomWord ()
{
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, wordList.Length);
string randomWord = wordList[randomIndex];

return randomWord;
}
```

Then there is the WordManagerscript that tracks the active word,word spawner etc. Here is the code for the word to be added:

```
public void AddWord ()
{
Word word = new Word(WordGenerator.GetRandomWord(), 
wordSpawner.SpawnWord());
wordsList.Add(word);
}
```

**Edit**

I have been trying to get the word spawner to work but to no avail. I had followed some word spawner tutorials but doesn't seem to work as the SpawnWord() method is used by another class i.e the word manager class....

```
public WordSpawner wordSpawner;

public  bool hasActiveWord;
public  Word activeWord;



public void AddWord()
{
    WordDisplay wordDisplay = wordSpawner.SpawnWord();

    Word word = new Word("boat", wordDisplay);//WordGenerator.GetRandomWord()


    Debug.Log(word.word);

    words.Add(word);
```

I'm not able to get this to work.....

Comment: Please do not delete & re-post duplicate questions. Instead, edit your old question to address the feedback you've been given in comments. This will have the same effect of "bumping" your question to the top of the active list to get more attention, without losing visibility on its history or creating redundant entries.

Comment: @DMGregory, will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

> In the WordSpawner.cs file, I'm trying to set the limit of the length of words that are displayed. for eg. in the first 15 seconds I want the length of words to be 3/4 and between 15-30 seconds 5/6 and after that any random length from 3 - 9. Is there any way to achieve this?

You could try checking the length of the word, and if not compatible, find another word. A string's length (the number of characters in said string), which happens to also be a word can be retrieved with `String.length`.

To get the time since something has happened, simply save the value of `Time.time` when said 'something' (ie. when the game starts) happens. You can then find the elapsed time by simply subtracting that stored value from the current `Time.time`. It is usually done in the `Update()` function.

> Also, I want to show the wave number on the screen like in the z-type game. How can I achieve this functionality.

Just add a variable to store the number and you can display it onto a `Text` label by setting the value of `Text.text`.

Comment: I have added the time.time script and it works fine...However I'm unable to get the wave number working..there needs to be sometime for the wae number to be displayed but with time.time being used, there is no time lag between the words that are displayed...i was just playing the z-type game...noticed that each wave increases the number of words that are displayed and not just the length...is there any way this can be done...

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the variable that stores the wave number...?

Comment: no, let me try that...will get back if it doesn't work